# Enforce order in which jobs executed by ThreadPoolExecutor finish

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a bunch of demanding operations **that can run in parallel but they have to finish in certain order**. By finish I mean write the results to a file. Of course I could re-order the results when all jobs are finished but I'd like to avoid that (especially because the results might be too big to be kept in memory).

I use a modified `ThreadPoolExecutor` to run the jobs in parallel that makes sure that only limited number of jobs is running at a time to reduce the memory consumption.

My idea is that each job will have a reference to the previous one and before writing the results it will wait until the previous one is done (if necessary). It seems like a simple synchronization problem but as I'm not experienced in this kind of stuff I'd like to hear an opinion if it's actually going to work as intended. Also regarding the memory management. Once a job is finished, the garbage collector should be able to remove it from memory.

```
abstract public class WaitingJob extends Job {

    /** Job to wait for before we finish this job */
    protected WaitingJob previousJob;

    /** Job status */
    protected boolean finished = false;

    public WaitingJob(WaitingJob previousJob) {
        this.previousJob = previousJob;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform the actual job (which might decide to wait for the previous one)
        runWithWaiting();

        // Wake up any job that's waiting for us.
        synchronized (this) {
            finished = true;
            notifyAll();
        }

        // Release memory (manually, to break the chain).
        previousJob = null;
    }

    /** If the previous job is not finished yet, let's wait for it. */
    protected void waitForPreviousJob() throws InterruptedException {
        if (previousJob != null) {
            synchronized (previousJob) {
                while (!previousJob.finished) {
                    previousJob.wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /** Perform the job with the possibility to wait on the previous one. */
    protected abstract void runWithWaiting();
}
```

Sample job:

```
class SampleJob extends WaitingJob {
    @Override
    protected void runWithWaiting() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);  // Do heavy work
            waitForPreviousJob();
            // Write down work
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I run couple of tests on this and it seems to behave as it should but I'm not sure if there are any dangerous moments.

Also, are there any existing better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me this should work and is a reasonable solution.  The only potential issue is that, depending on the rest of your code, it might be possible for all the threads to be occupied with jobs that are waiting on a job that hasn't yet been assigned a thread, resulting in a deadlock (e.g., with four threads in the pool, jobs 2-5 finish and put their threads in a wait state while job 1 can't get a thread since they are all occupied).  That might not be applicable to your situation, though.

Comment: I'm inserting the jobs in the executor in the order in which they should be processed and it goes through the blocking queue. By the definition of a queue I expect that it shouldn't be possible for the job 2 to get a thread before the job 1. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That should be fine as long as the order that the jobs are submitted to the queue is well defined, for example if they are all submitted from the same thread.  If the jobs are submitted from multiple threads, you may want to check the specific blocking queue implementation and configuration.

Comment: Yes, it is well defined. The job generation is a rather cheap operation so it's handled by a single thread that is pushing the jobs into Blockqueue inside the Executor.